# Pytest NameError: name 'period_df' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest

I am trying to use pytest for pandas dataframe as below:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("file_type", "expected", [(input_file, period_df)])
def test_validation(file_type, expected):
    params = {'req': {'run_id': 'iter_no_test', 'ip_weight': 'ip_weigh_test'}}

    actual = validation(file_type, **params)
    pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(expected, actual)
```

where period_df is as follows:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def period_df():
    expected = pd.DataFrame(period_expected_dict)

    expected_columns = expected.columns.to_list()
    expected = check_dtype(expected, expected_columns, expected_period_keymap)

    return expected
```

I am getting an error

```
test_validation_mix.py:205: in <module>
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("file_type", "expected", [(input_file, period_df)])
E   NameError: name 'period_df' is not defined
```

I also tried without fixture by making period_df as a global variable but the same error persists.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You cannot use a fixture as a function, as you do in `parametrize` - use a plain function instead.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen it didn't work

Comment: How it didn't work? What did you do?

Comment: I removed the fixture decorator.Can you please give some reference if I missed something

Comment: You mean yo get the same error? That would just mean that `period_df` is not known at that point. Where do you define it, and how do you import it? Without seeing more of the code I can only guess...

Comment: @MrBeanBremen it is defined just outside the test function. Also as mentioned in the post I tried with the period_df as global var but the same error persists

Comment: You mean you define it in the same file and it is not found anyway? (besides, you have to call it, e.g. `period_df()` instead of `period_df`, but that is another problem).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217261/discussion-between-pragyan-and-mrbean-bremen).